# "Likescount" and "CommentCount" returns null from publishing pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have a search function that connects to "LikesCount" and "CommentCount"properties (social bar).

Example:

```
 let localQuery = SearchQueryBuilder.create('', {TrimDuplicates: false})
     ContentTypeId:${Constants.NewsArticleContentTypeId}* (RefinableString101<>GTSet|#${Constants.TargetAudienceTermSetId} OR GP0|#${targetAudienceQueyry})`)
        .text(query)
        .sortList({Property: 'FirstPublishedDate', Direction:SortDirection.Descending})
        .selectProperties('Title','intraSubheadOWSTEXT','FirstPublishedDate','LikesCount','CommentCount','NewsTags', 'DefaultEncodingURL','PictureThumbnailURL', 'intraContainsVideoOWSBOOL')
        .rowLimit(4);
```

But it return null, even if articles (publishing pages) have "likes" and "comments".
It should retrieve from this (social bar) that can be found on site pages:

[image]

In my schema, I have this mapped properties:
[image]

[image]